# Rendering individual fields in template in a custom form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am having trouble rendering individual fields in my template. I have a custom form that renders a multichoice widget and Charfield. I want to render the widget and Charfield individually, so I can place the Charfield on the right of the widget rather than on the bottom (which is what Django does by default). Is there a way to call individual fields in my form in the template?

forms.py

```
class UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       disease=kwargs.pop('disease', None)
       super(UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Outcome.objects.filter(relevantdisease_id=disease),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome'].label="Treatment Outcomes"

       outcome_qs=Outcome.objects.filter(relevantdisease_id=disease)
       for outcome in outcome_qs:
       self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk] = forms.CharField(required=False)
       self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk].label = "Outcome Value"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`{{ form.fieldname }}` will render only the field widget by its name.

Check out [Customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Answer (score 5):

The following code could be helpful to someone. Here is a way to get a rendering field with `fieldname` from a `form`:

```
form.fields[fieldname].get_bound_field(form, fieldname)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly clear how this works, but it seemed to do the trick for me. I have a set of dynamic fields in my form that I need to render given their dynamic names, and this returned the object to be rendered as I needed it. It would help to get a better understanding of what it does/how though.

Comment: Is this in `view.py` or in the template? Adding reference or working example can help.

Comment: @Gathide It's python code in the view.py